# SharePoint List View Filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, sharepoint-list-filter

I have a choice column "Position" which I am referencing in the new list view filter to create a bunch of different views for departments. Each department can only view certain relevant "Position" choices.

Every view I have made so far works fine, but for my last view, I have 19 choices that could be a possible selection that will show up for this departments view.

All of my other views had 6 or less options. In the filter section, I have filled in 10 options and the "show more columns" option disappears from adding more.

Why is that? And is there a way around this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default behavior of SharePoint.

You can only use 10 conditions in list view filter.

**Workaround** (Not tested):

Try setting the list view query using PowerShell: [SharePoint Online: PowerShell to Update List View](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-update-list-view.html)

View query requires [CAML Query](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema).

Comment: What if I created a broad value for the filter, then used a lookup column to determine the actual position?

Comment: It might work with "contains" operator in filter condition (as  long as you have less than 10 conditions). But again users have to take care the selection of lookup value while creating/updating list items.

Comment: Or... Can I have a different column with sub values, and have that column only show up when you are entering a new list item in a certain view?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Are you using SharePoint default list forms or customized forms?

Comment: I am using default